# Optimize join query postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query, and am trying to optimize it.
I'm using few rows, but in production it will have millions of rows in each table...

I have put index on every table, and for some joins postgres are using index, but for some not...

Can you help me with optimizing this query?

What index can I put on tables to optimize it?
Is there other forms of writing this query that performs better?

```
SELECT mm4.dezenas_id, mm4.dezenas, 
mm4.min as mmm4min,mm4.max as mm4max, 
mm5.min as mmm5min,mm5.max as mm5max, 
mm6.min as mmm6min,mm6.max as mm6max, 
mm7.min as mmm7min,mm7.max as mm7max, 
mm8.min as mmm8min,mm8.max as mm8max 
FROM mm4 
inner join mm5 on 
mm4.dezenas_id = mm5.dezenas_id and 
mm4.dezenas = mm5.dezenas 
inner join mm6 on 
mm4.dezenas_id = mm6.dezenas_id 
and mm4.dezenas = mm6.dezenas 
inner join mm7 on 
mm4.dezenas_id = mm7.dezenas_id and 
mm4.dezenas = mm7.dezenas 
inner join mm8 on 
mm4.dezenas_id = mm8.dezenas_id and 
mm4.dezenas = mm8.dezenas;
```

Sorry, updated with texts and with SQLPro suggested index:

Explain Analyse:

```
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                         
        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------
 Nested Loop  (cost=333.99..890.51 rows=1 width=104) (actual time=11.963..44663.303 rows=16153908 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ((mm4.dezenas_id = mm8.dezenas_id) AND (mm4.dezenas = mm8.dezenas))
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=333.57..887.36 rows=6 width=288) (actual time=11.899..4464.242 rows=1189812 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ((mm4.dezenas_id = mm7.dezenas_id) AND (mm4.dezenas = mm7.dezenas))
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=333.16..867.17 rows=38 width=216) (actual time=11.844..596.322 rows=122763 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((mm4.dezenas_id = mm6.dezenas_id) AND (mm4.dezenas = mm6.dezenas))
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=332.75..681.82 rows=351 width=144) (actual time=11.769..47.106 rows=19056 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((mm4.dezenas_id = mm5.dezenas_id) AND (mm4.dezenas = mm5.dezenas))
                     ->  Seq Scan on mm4  (cost=0.00..106.76 rows=4776 width=72) (actual time=0.022..2.992 rows=4776 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=199.10..199.10 rows=8910 width=72) (actual time=11.437..11.438 rows=8910 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1033kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on mm5  (cost=0.00..199.10 rows=8910 width=72) (actual time=0.049..4.184 rows=8910 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using mm6_idx11 on mm6  (cost=0.41..0.51 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.020..0.022 rows=6 loops
=19056)
                     Index Cond: ((dezenas = mm5.dezenas) AND (dezenas_id = mm5.dezenas_id))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
         ->  Index Only Scan using mm7_idx11 on mm7  (cost=0.41..0.52 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.019..0.023 rows=10 loops=1227
63)
               Index Cond: ((dezenas = mm6.dezenas) AND (dezenas_id = mm6.dezenas_id))
               Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Index Only Scan using mm8_idx11 on mm8  (cost=0.41..0.51 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.020..0.024 rows=14 loops=1189812)
         Index Cond: ((dezenas = mm7.dezenas) AND (dezenas_id = mm7.dezenas_id))
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 28.352 ms
 Execution Time: 46482.239 ms
```

Create table script (all are the same):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mm{_mmsize} (
min int,
max int,
dezenas text,
dezenas_id text,
Primary key (dezenas, dezenas_id, min, max)
);
```

Create index script (all are the same):

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS mm{_mmsize}_idx11
ON
mm{_mmsize}(dezenas,dezenas_id) include ("min", "max");
```

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN as formatted text. Not just as images where the former text has been partially truncated away.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX X4 ON mm4 (dezenas_id, dezenas) INCLUDE ("min", "max");
CREATE INDEX X5 ON mm5 (dezenas_id, dezenas) INCLUDE ("min", "max");
CREATE INDEX X6 ON mm6 (dezenas_id, dezenas) INCLUDE ("min", "max");
CREATE INDEX X7 ON mm7 (dezenas_id, dezenas) INCLUDE ("min", "max");
CREATE INDEX X8 ON mm8 (dezenas_id, dezenas) INCLUDE ("min", "max");
```

Comment: Thanks! I have these index, but not with INCLUDE. Will try it!

Comment: INCLUDE is new since version 11 of PostGreSQL (2018) and the INCLUDE clause for index was first introduced in 2005 version of SQL Server